# angular ngrx store call multi http service into one effect and dispacth actions

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, fork-join

Hi i need call multi http service in parallel mode, and to goal this i use forkJoin, but when it's finished it not dispatch the actsions.

```
doSearchCliente$ = createEffect(() =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
         ofType(addCliente),
         switchMap(action => {
            const cliente$ = this.clienteService.ClienteById(action.id).pipe(
               map(response => addClienteSuccess({ response })),
               catchError(() => of(addClienteFailure())));
            const listino$ = this.clienteService.ListinoCollection(action.id).pipe(
               map(response => addListinoSuccess({ response })),
               catchError(() => of(addListinoFailure())));

            return forkJoin([cliente$, listino$]).pipe(
               mergeMap(response => [response[0], response[1]])
            );
         }),
      ));
```

can someone help me?

Comment: try to add the first oeprator after each map of each http request. I think forkJoin emits when all Obs ended. and when you do a http reqeust the observable tecnically does not end. So the first operator make those end

Comment: I call a map at each http! I don’t understand you

Comment: change   map(response => addClienteSuccess({ response })), for   map(response => addClienteSuccess({ response })), first(), and   map(response => addListinoSuccess({ response })), for   map(response => addListinoSuccess({ response })), first(), and add at the top of the file import {first} from 'rxjs/operators'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add the first oeprator after each map of each http request. forkJoin emits when all Observables ended. and when you do a http request the observables technically do not end. So the first operator make those end.

```
doSearchCliente$ = createEffect(() =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
         ofType(addCliente),
         switchMap(action => {
            const cliente$ = this.clienteService.ClienteById(action.id).pipe(
               first(),
               map(response => addClienteSuccess({ response })),
               catchError(() => of(addClienteFailure())));
            const listino$ = this.clienteService.ListinoCollection(action.id).pipe(
               first(),
               map(response => addListinoSuccess({ response })),
               catchError(() => of(addListinoFailure())));

            return forkJoin([cliente$, listino$]).pipe(
               mergeMap(response => [response[0], response[1]])
            );
         }),
      ));
```

Answer (score 0):

do you say this?

```
doSearchCliente$ = createEffect(() =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
         ofType(addCliente),
         switchMap(action => {
            const cliente$ = this.clienteService.ClienteById(action.id).pipe(
               map(response => addClienteSuccess({ response })),
               catchError(() => of(addClienteFailure())));
            const listino$ = this.clienteService.ListinoCollection(action.id).pipe(
               map(response => addListinoSuccess({ response })),
               catchError(() => of(addListinoFailure())));

            return forkJoin([cliente$]);
         }),
         switchMap(response => {
            return [response[0]];
         })
      ));
```

not work! :(